# alternative to text valign in css

Tags: html, css

Do you know how can I make text vertically centred? I need something like valign attribute, but written in css. Any ideas?

Comment: Please post your html structure, the css to be applied will depend on this

Answer (score 6):

There's is no universal answer to this. Unfortunataly, no, there is no true equivalent in CSS. Some options depending on the context of your particular layout:

- for one line of text, giving the text a `line-height` equal to the height of the container will center it vertically
- if not worrying about IE, you can use `display: table-cell` on the container and add `vertical-align: middle`
- use JS to calculate the necessary positioning or padding/margin needed to center the element after calculating the heights of the container and child element.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [vertical-align](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp) property

Comment: That's easy to say but considerably harder to do.